# How to store a Drawable/Bitmap in SQLite (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap, drawable, android-drawable

I would like to pass the Int Value of a Drawable through the Bundle in CreateActivity. From this Int value (Resource ID) I would like to use it to create an Event Object that is stored in a SQLLITE DB. When the program generates a listview it should be able to use this Int value to assign its associated Drawable to a part of the listview.

**What should I do to store a Drawable in an SQLite DB or atleast store the INT Value in the DB? **

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

ListView listView;
int lastIndex = -1;
ArrayList<Event> lstEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();

// detail view
TextView tvTitle, tvTime, tvDate;
ImageView ivPic;
View vw_master;

boolean _isBack = true;

ImageButton add;

String title;
String date;
String time;
int resId;

static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // // get detail controls
    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
    tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
    tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    ivPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);


    /////////////////////////////////LISTVIEW////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, lstEvents);

    // attach adapter to a list view
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    /////////////////////////////////LISTVIEW////////////////////////////////////////




    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////

    List<Event> events = db.getAllContacts();

    adapter.addAll(events);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();






}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.add:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, lstEvents);

    // attach adapter to a list view
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
            title = b.getString("TITLE");
            time = b.getString("TIME");
            date = b.getString("DATE");

            // retrieving bitmap from CreateActivity

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) b.getParcelable("DRAWABLE");

            // converting from bitmap to drawable
            Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

            // Event newEvent = new Event();
            // newEvent.set_date(date);
            // newEvent.set_title(title);
            // newEvent.set_time(time);

            // set drawable
            // newEvent.set_drawable(drawable);

            // lstEvents.add(newEvent);

            // adapter.addAll(lstEvents);
            // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            ///////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
            /**
             * CRUD OPERATIONS
             */

            Log.e("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
            db.addEvent(new Event(0, title, time, date, drawable));

            // Reading all contacts
            Log.e("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
            // List<Event> events = db.getAllContacts();
            List<Event> events = db.getAllContacts();
            adapter.addAll(events);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //logging all events

            for (Event ev : events) {
                String log = "Id: " + ev.get_Id() + " ,Title: "
                        + ev.get_title() + " ,Date: " + ev.get_date();
                // Writing Contacts to log
                Log.e("Name: ", log);

            }

            ///////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
        }

    }
}
}
```

**Event Class**

```
public class Event {
public int _id;
public String _title;
public String _time;
public String _date;

//drawable
public String _bitmap;


public Event() {
    super();
};

public Event(int id, String title, String time, String date, String bitmap) {
    this._id = id;
    this._title = title;
    this._time = time;
    this._date = date;
    this._bitmap = bitmap;
};

public Event(JSONObject object){
    try {
        this._id = object.getInt("id");
        this._title = object.getString("title");
        this._time = object.getString("time");
        this._date = object.getString("date");
   } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

// Event.fromJson(jsonArray);
public static ArrayList<Event> fromJson(JSONArray jsonObjects) {
       ArrayList<Event> users = new ArrayList<Event>();
       for (int i = 0; i < jsonObjects.length(); i++) {
           try {
              users.add(new Event(jsonObjects.getJSONObject(i)));
           } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
      }
      return users;
}



public int get_Id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_Id(int _Id) {
    this._id = _Id;
}


public String get_title() {
    return _title;
}

public void set_title(String _title) {
    this._title = _title;
}

public String get_bitmap() {
    return _bitmap;
}

public void set_drawable(String _bitmap) {
    this._bitmap = _bitmap;
}

public String get_time() {
    return _time;
}

public void set_time(String _time) {
    this._time = _time;
}

public String get_date() {
    return _date;
}

public void set_date(String _date) {
    this._date = _date;
}

}
```

**DatabaseHandler**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scheduleManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_EVENTS = "events";


// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
private static final String KEY_BITMAP = "bitmap";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EVENTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TIME + " TEXT," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT" + KEY_BITMAP + " TEXT )";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EVENTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */


//adding an event (NEEDS TO ADD DRAWABLE)
 public void addEvent(Event event) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, event.get_Id()); //Event ID
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, event.get_title()); // Event Title
        values.put(KEY_TIME, event.get_time()); // Event Time
        values.put(KEY_DATE, event.get_date()); // Event Date
        values.put(KEY_BITMAP, event.get_bitmap()); // Event Drawable

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_EVENTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

   // Getting single contact
   public Event getEvent(int id) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

       Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_EVENTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
               KEY_TITLE, KEY_TIME, KEY_DATE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
               new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
       if (cursor != null)
           cursor.moveToFirst();

       Event event = new Event(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
               cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), null, null);
       // return contact
       return event;
   }


    // Getting All Contacts
   public List<Event> getAllContacts() {
      List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
      // Select All Query
      String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS;

      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

      // looping through all rows and adding to list
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          do {
              Event event = new Event();
              event.set_Id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
              event.set_title(cursor.getString(1));
              event.set_time(cursor.getString(2));
              event.set_date(cursor.getString(3));
              // Adding contact to list
              eventList.add(event);
          } while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }

      // return contact list
      return eventList;
  }

// Getting event Count
    public int getEventsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

 // Updating single contact
    public int updateEvent(Event event) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, event.get_title());
        values.put(KEY_TIME, event.get_time());
        values.put(KEY_DATE, event.get_date());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_EVENTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(event.get_Id()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteEvent(Event event) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_EVENTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(event.get_Id()) });
        db.close();
    }
}
```

**Create Activity**

```
public class CreateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText etTitle;
Button btDate;
Button btTime;
Button btPic;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    //onclicklistener
    findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_back).setOnClickListener(this);

    etTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
    btDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
    btTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
    btPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_picture);

}

// Will be called via the onClick attribute
// of the buttons in main.xml
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_confirm:
        String title = etTitle.getText().toString();
        String time = btTime.getText().toString();
        String date = btDate.getText().toString();


        Drawable drawable = btPic.getCompoundDrawables()[1];
        Log.e("DRAWABLE", "DrawableId" + drawable);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();


        Log.e("LOG", title);
        Log.e("LOG", time);
        Log.e("LOG", date);


        Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
        newBundle.putString("TITLE", title);
        newBundle.putString("TIME", time);
        newBundle.putString("DATE", date);

        //Trying to pass a drawable from one activity to another
        newBundle.putParcelable("DRAWABLE", bitmap);


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(newBundle);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();

        break;

    case R.id.btn_back:
        finish();
        break;
    }

}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public void showPicturePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new PicturePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "picturePicker");
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Store images in database isn't recommended. You must store images in internal or external memory and store a reference of your image in your database.

```
// GET INT VALUE FROM RESOURCE
int home = R.drawable.home;

// SET IMAGE RESOURCE
img.setImageResource(home);
```

Comment: Are the resources already stored in memory? They are located inside the drawable folder, so what would I be looking to do to get the reference to the images?

Comment: If the images are inside the `/drawable` folder, then `R.drawable.image_name` is actually an integer. Store this integer into the DB and re-use it next time.

Comment: How do I convert from an integer back to the drawable though?

Comment: For this, would I store `R.drawable.home` , or just `home` ?
Also, will this work for string resources as well?

Comment: @VishnuHaridas Is that integer consistent? Won't it change when recompiling the app or adding another image?

Comment: Correct, the `R.drawable.xyz` integer value can change. Better approach is to create a static mapping of the `R.drawable.*` items to a set of string keys, and store this string key in the database. When querying from the DB, you will get this string key, and find the matching `R.drawable.` id from the previous static mapping.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put images in internal memory of your project then put your images in assets folder and save their names in sqlite then use below code to display images:

```
 String imageUrl = imgArraList.get(position).getUrl();
/*imageUrl variable will contain image name that should be available in assets folder.*/
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open(imageUrl));
    touch.setImageBitmap(bitmap, null, 1.0f, 2.0f);
```